# How much of the mass of a supermassive black hole comes from dark matter?

Tags: black-holes, dark-matter

How much of the mass of a supermassive black hole comes from dark matter?

Assuming cold dark matter exists and that it doesn't bank up and get pushed away from black holes like some baryonic matter.
Assuming the supermassive BH is one of the first in the universe and has been sucking in DM since then.

Answer (score 6):

[One estimate](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2041) is less than 10%. But you should see follow-up papers (click on "cited by"...) for other opinions.

Comment: interesting paper, I was thinking more of quasars and the early universe. I was also wondering what models of quasars would have to be adjusted to include dark matter?

Comment: The main DM debate over quasars seems to be whether they are located in the biggest concentrations of DM or not. http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2199 says not... For the other view, look up "dark gulping" for the idea that supermassive black holes formed from DM.